# Binary Tree for integer storage of C language

Tags: c

I have tried to build a binary tree for integer storage as the following code.
There seems no error message in Eclipse. But when I tried to run it, the program stop instantly with windows stop error notification.

```
Node* insertNode(Node *root, int value){
Node* temp = root;
if(temp != NULL){
    while(temp->left != NULL || temp->right != NULL){
        if(value < temp->data){
            temp = temp->left;
        }
        else{
            temp = temp->right;
        }
    }
}
Node* new = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
if(value < temp->data){
    new->data = value;
    new->left = new->right = NULL;
    temp->left = new;
    return temp;
}
else{
    new->data = value;
    new->left = new->right = NULL;
    temp->right = new;
    return temp;
    }
}
```

This is a function for creating the binary tree.
I would like to get a value any save it to the existing binary tree.
After the right place has been found in the tree. I would like to create a new node with the value and store that as the pointer of parent.
Here is the struct of Node.

```
struct Node{
int data;
struct Node *left;
struct Node *right;
};
typedef struct Node Node;
```

[Here is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOZFE.png)

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: would help to see the error message, yes?  most likely a null pointer issue

Comment: If you are inserting the 1st value, `root = NULL`, then in your insert function you derefernce `temp`, e.g. `if(value < temp->data)` invoking *Undefined Behavior* (and a likely SegFault). Handle the case where you are adding the 1st value to your tree.

Comment: Thank you for the comment very much. I have tried to add the case as you say. The problem is solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(temp != NULL){
    while(temp->left != NULL || temp->right != NULL){
        if(value < temp->data){
            temp = temp->left;
        }
        else{
            temp = temp->right;
        }
    }
}
Node* new = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
if(value < temp->data){
```

The `if` tests if `temp` is `NULL`. So apparently, `temp` might be `NULL`. Since the `if` only runs if `temp` isn't `NULL`, if `temp` was `NULL`, it still is when we get to the `malloc`.

But then we access `temp->data` unconditionally. But what if `temp` is `NULL`?

```
if(temp != NULL){ // temp might be NULL here
    while(temp->left != NULL || temp->right != NULL){
        if(value < temp->data){
            temp = temp->left;
        }
        else{
            temp = temp->right;
        }
    }
}
// if temp was NULL there, it still is here
Node* new = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
if(value < temp->data){ // Uh oh, we dereference temp here, what if it's NULL?
```

Boom.